# Identify name of default color palette being used by seaborn or matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn, visualization

[image]
This is the color palette, seaborn has used by default when I used a column with categorical variables to color the scatter points.
**Is there a way to get the name or colors of color-palette being used?**
I get this color scheme in the beginning but as soon as I use a diff scheme for a plotly, I can't get to this palette for the same chart.
This is not the scheme which comes from `sns.color_palette`. This can also be a matplotlib color scheme.

**Minimum reproducible example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px

# download data
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.statlearning.com/s/Auto.csv")
df.head()

# remove rows with "?"
df.drop(df.index[~df.horsepower.str.isnumeric()], axis=0, inplace=True)
df['horsepower'] = pd.to_numeric(df.horsepower, errors='coerce')

# plot 1 (gives the desired color-palette)
fig = sns.PairGrid(df, vars=df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['cylinders','origin','name'])].tolist(), hue='cylinders')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(17,15)
fig.map_diag(sns.histplot)
fig.map_upper(sns.scatterplot)
fig.map_lower(sns.kdeplot)
fig.add_legend(ncol=5, loc=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05), borderaxespad=0, frameon=False);

# plot 2
# Converting column cylinder to factor before using for 'color'
df.cylinders = df.cylinders.astype('category')

# Scatter plot - Cylinders as hue
pal = ['#fdc086','#386cb0','#beaed4','#33a02c','#f0027f']
col_map = dict(zip(sorted(df.cylinders.unique()), pal))
fig = px.scatter(df, y='mpg', x='year', color='cylinders', 
                 color_discrete_map=col_map, 
                 hover_data=['name','origin'])
fig.update_layout(width=800, height=400, plot_bgcolor='#fff')
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=8, line=dict(width=0.2,color='DarkSlateGrey')),
                  selector=dict(mode='markers'))
fig.show()

# plot 1 run again
fig = sns.PairGrid(df, vars=df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['cylinders','origin','name'])].tolist(), hue='cylinders')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(17,15)
fig.map_diag(sns.histplot)
fig.map_upper(sns.scatterplot)
fig.map_lower(sns.kdeplot)
fig.add_legend(ncol=5, loc=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05), borderaxespad=0, frameon=False);
```

Comment: did you try `sns.color_pallete()` ?  According to the documentation it will return the current color palette.

Comment: Yes, I tried sns.color_palette. It gave some other scheme with very different colors.

Comment: It would help if you provide the minimum code to reproduce the charts with that color pallete

Comment: coming up......

Comment: Have added the code. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, you're defining the palette that's going into plotly explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific palette you have mentioned is the [`cubehelix`](https://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/%7Edag/CUBEHELIX/) and you can get it using:

```
sns.cubehelix_palette()
```

[image: cubehelix]

You can get the colours using indexing:

```py
sns.cubehelix_palette()[:]

# [[0.9312692223325372, 0.8201921796082118, 0.7971480974663592],
#  [0.8559578605899612, 0.6418993116910497, 0.6754191211563135],
#  [0.739734329496642, 0.4765280683170713, 0.5959617419736206],
#  [0.57916573903086, 0.33934576125314425, 0.5219003947563425],
#  [0.37894937987025, 0.2224702044652721, 0.41140014301575434],
#  [0.1750865648952205, 0.11840023306916837, 0.24215989137836502]]
```

In general, checking the [official docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html) or in the case when you need to check some defaults of seaborn (which is the only case when you don't know what the palette is, otherwise you know because you're the one defining it), you can always check the github code (eg. [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/9425588d3498755abd93960df4ab05ec1a8de3ef/seaborn/utils.py#L86) or [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/9425588d3498755abd93960df4ab05ec1a8de3ef/seaborn/axisgrid.py#L212)).

Answer (score 1):

In your first graph the `cylinders` is a continuous variable of type `int64` and seaborn is using a single color, in this case purple, and shading it to indicate the scale of the value, so that 8 cylinders would be darker than 4.  This is done on purpose so you can easily tell what is what by the shade of the color.

Once you convert to categorical halfway through there is no longer such a relationship between the cylinder values, i.e. 8 cylinders is not twice as much a 4 cylinders anymore, they are essentially two totally different categories.  To avoid associating the shade of color with the scale of the variable (since the values are no longer continuous and the relationship doesn't exist) a categorical color palette will be used by default, such that every color is distinct from the other.

In order to solve your problem, you will need to cast `cylinders` back to `int64` prior to running your final chart with

`df.cylinders = df.cylinders.astype('int64')`

This will restore the variable to a continuous one and will allow seaborn to use gradients of the same color to represent the size of the values and your final plot will look just like the first one.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# download data
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.statlearning.com/s/Auto.csv")
df.head()

# remove rows with "?"
df.drop(df.index[~df.horsepower.str.isnumeric()], axis=0, inplace=True)
df['horsepower'] = pd.to_numeric(df.horsepower, errors='coerce')

# plot 1 (gives the desired color-palette)
fig = sns.PairGrid(df, vars=df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['cylinders','origin','name'])].tolist(), hue='cylinders')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(17,15)
fig.map_diag(sns.histplot)
fig.map_upper(sns.scatterplot)
fig.map_lower(sns.kdeplot)
fig.add_legend(ncol=5, loc=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05), borderaxespad=0, frameon=False);

# plot 2
# Converting column cylinder to factor before using for 'color'
df.cylinders = df.cylinders.astype('category')

# Scatter plot - Cylinders as hue
pal = ['#fdc086','#386cb0','#beaed4','#33a02c','#f0027f']
col_map = dict(zip(sorted(df.cylinders.unique()), pal))
fig = px.scatter(df, y='mpg', x='year', color='cylinders', 
                 color_discrete_map=col_map, 
                 hover_data=['name','origin'])
fig.update_layout(width=800, height=400, plot_bgcolor='#fff')
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=8, line=dict(width=0.2,color='DarkSlateGrey')),
                  selector=dict(mode='markers'))
fig.show()

# plot 1 run again
df.cylinders = df.cylinders.astype('int64')
fig = sns.PairGrid(df, vars=df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['cylinders','origin','name'])].tolist(), hue='cylinders')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(17,15)
fig.map_diag(sns.histplot)
fig.map_upper(sns.scatterplot)
fig.map_lower(sns.kdeplot)
fig.add_legend(ncol=5, loc=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05), borderaxespad=0, frameon=False);
```

Output

Answer (score 0):

One way to get it back is with `sns.set().` But that doesn't tell us the name of the color scheme.